# Jenkins not responding to github webhooks

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks, jenkins-pipeline

Nothing i try seems to trigger my Jenkins webhooks from github

Things to know

1. My Jenkins instance sits behind a Nginx proxy
2. I am using the Organization type Jenkins project with a Jenkinsfile
3. The git user used is using a personal access token and has organization rights and all needed permissions 
   [image]
4. I have security setup on the Jenkins instance so my Jenkins webhook url is https://foo:bar@jenkins.doctify.co.uk/github-webhook/
5. The webhook has the accurate set of permissions 
   [image]
6. This gets the green tick and a 200 response from the Jenkins instance
7. When using polling to trigger the branch indexing this works correctly
8. In the logs i only see this sometimes and never a pull request event

   ```
   INFO: Received POST for https://github.com/doctify/platform
   Jul 14, 2016 4:13:40 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
   ```
9. My Organization configuration 
   [image]
10. Jenkins Version 2.13, Git Version 2.7.5

Questions

1. How do I get this to work?
2. How do I make it better and have the organization plugin create the webhooks automatically the way I'm sure its meant to do?

Comment: @jirong-hu i think you had this problem. Do you have any input on how you fixed it